# Best way to listen for click event across components in Angular 13

Tags: angular

I have a top-nav component which contains a nav menu with a dropdown. When I click the dropdown link, I'd like a background overlay to appear beneath the dropdown menu and covering the page.

I have this hierachy of components.
main.component.ts > header.component.ts > top-navigation.component.ts

The click occurs in the top-navigation.component.html and I need to listen for this in the main.component.ts as in the main.component.html I have a span (with corresponding css which is waiting for a class of `active` to be added on click).
`<span class="page-overlay"></span>`

Using @Output with EventEmitter doesn't seem right as I'd need to emit up from top-navigation to header, then emit again from the header up to main (but I could be wrong...).

Should an Observable be used to do this or is that overkill to simply pass an event from one component to another? I have a navigation service but have read an Observable shouldn't be listened for inside a service.

Comment: You can either emit your `click` event back to the component where you'd like to listen to it, or use a observable in a shared service for communication between the components.

Comment: Both are possible (2nd assuming a service as Mike says). I suggest thinking about the role of each component and any future responsibilities they may get. Might header in the future want to know about the event and take more action than pass on the information. Unless you have a specific problem to solve, question is opinion based.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but as I understand your question, you don't really need to communicate components.
If you want, for example, blur the page when hovering (or clicking) in the navbar, what you can do is apllying a background with any dark color, with 100% at width and height, and higher z-index than the page, but lower than the dropdown.